# Parsing a json using Angular js

Tags: json, angularjs

```
{
    "statusCode": "000",
    "statusMessage": "Record Successfully Fetched",
    "dsStatusCode": "000",
    "dsStatusMessage": "Record Successfully Fetched",
    "businessInput": null,
    "businessOutput": {
        "systemCircleId": "2",
        "category": [
            {
                "categoryId": "abcs",
                "sys": "5ID",
                "displayName": "National Roaming Recharge",
                "packsList": [
                    {
                        "amount": "79",
                        "benefits": "dsdsdsds",
                        "packId": "1344",
                        "processingFees": "70.3",
                        "serviceTax": "8.7",
                        "validity": "30 Days",
                        "volume": "0.0",
                        "isTop5": "no",
                        "fileName": "null"
                    },
                    {
                        "amount": "188",
                        "benefits": "Roaming Tariff - Incoming Free, Outgoing local @ 80p/min, STD @1.15Rs/min with Talk Time 120 in main A/c",
                        "packId": "1263",
                        "fess": "47.3",
                        "serviceTax": "20.7",
                        "validity": "28 Days",
                        "volume": "0.0",
                        "isTop5": "no",
                        "fileName": "null"
                    },
                    {
                        "amount": "306",
                        "benefits": "FTT 306 with Roaming Tariff - Incoming Free, Outgoing local @ 80p/min, STD @1.15Rs/min",
                        "packId": "1290",
                        "processingFees": "0",
                        "serviceTax": "33.7",
                        "validity": "28 Days",
                        "volume": "0.0",
                        "isTop5": "no",
                        "fileName": "null"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to parse this json to filter `packlist` for each category id using angularjs

Comment: So, what have you tried yourself and where does it go wrong?

Comment: It's already JSON, So what do you want/

Comment: not able to use ng-repeat within ng-repeat

 <div ng-app="myForm" ng-controller="myController" >
 {{businessOutput}}
  <p ng-repeat="main in mains">

  
          <p ng-repeat="submain in main.businessOutput">
     {{submain.category.categoryId}}
    
           </p>
    </p>
</div>

Comment: `{{submain.category[0].categoryId}}` as `category` is an array thus you need to use indexer

Comment: <div ng-app="myForm" ng-controller="myController" >

  <p ng-repeat="main in mains">

  
          <p ng-repeat="submain in main.businessOutput">
         {{submain.category[0].categoryId}}
   
           </p>
    </p>
</div>

Comment: Don't just past the code. Clearly define the problem

Comment: i am getting this json as a response from a service.

I need to consume it using angular

i wantto  filter the packlist of each category id

I have written the above code  and not sure how to iterate over a packlist

Comment: @Ssk what are you actually attempting to do? Could you explain exactly what you wish to see on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

assign a variable to the JSON you have. and use scope.$eval on the variable

Example

```
var jsonVar = { "statusCode": "000",
    "statusMessage": "Record Successfully Fetched",
    "dsStatusCode": "000",
    "dsStatusMessage": "Record Successfully Fetched",
    "businessInput": null
    }

scope.$eval(jsonVar) // this gives the object on which you can do the ng-repeat
```

if you still have problems. Try using JSON.stringify(jsonVar) and then perform a scope.$eval on the this.

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonVar);
scope.$eval(jsonString);// This returns a object too
```